# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have posted the code first and the question below

```
 def create

     new_tag = Tag.new(name: params[:create_new][:name],
                       description: "TEST STRING", #TODO
                       user: @current_user,)

     if new_tag.save
        create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag_id(params[:assignment_id], new_tag.id)
        flash[:success] = I18n.t('tag created successfully')
        redirect_to :back
     else
        flash[:error] = I18n.t('error creating tag')
        redirect_to :back
     end
  end

  def create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag_id(assignment_id, tag_id)
    puts "assignment_id: #{assignment_id}"
    puts "tag_id: #{tag_id}"

    tag = Tag.find(tag_id)
    create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag(assignment_id, tag)
  end

  def create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag(assignment_id, t)
    if !t.assignment.exists(assignment_id)
      assign = Assignment.find(assignment_id)
      t.assignments << (assign)
    end
  end
```

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
Rails.root: /Markus

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:84:in `create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag'
app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:80:in `create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag_id'
app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:18:in `create'
```

I'm confused as to why Ruby thinks create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag takes 0 arguments and why it thinks its only getting 1?

Note: I'm only calling create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag_id currently to show that that method takes two arguments and RonR recognizes that it takes two and is getting passed two.  Because that call works, I'm confused as to why the second fn call is not working.

Comment: Can you show your params (from the error web page)?

Comment: Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"U4z67ktn1hSE94h79RAnb2VZYsotIm0ZTUFiVoIIvno=",
 "create_new"=>{"name"=>"asdgamynewtaggasdadsg"},
 "commit"=>"Save Changes",
 "locale"=>"en",
 "assignment_id"=>"1"}

Comment: Which line is the 84th line in tags_controller.rb?

Comment: I guess `if !t.assignment.exists(assignment_id)` is the 84th line.

Comment: Use `exists?` instead of `exists`

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't `create_assignment_tag_association_from_tag`, the issue is **inside** that function. `exists` is wrong. You're after [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class).

Comment: Though, I'm having a hard time finding a method `exists` that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: It's `arel`'s SQL `EXISTS` for constructing queries, it's available in many ActiveRecord's objects, totally different thing: https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/select_manager.rb